# Zenity multi-choice from keyboard

Tags: scripts, zenity

I was looking for a `zenity` script that would offer choice between multiple commands (logout options, programs). Looking at the script discussed [here](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?id=279) (that uses the `--radiolist` option) I have noticed that it provides a list of options that cannot be selected from the keyboard.

But the one I have found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1829028) can do precisely that, therefore I want to share it here. I think it is useful.

Answer (score 4):

The general form of the script (with UPPERCASE for editable entries) is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ask=`zenity --list --title="WHATEVER Options" --column="0" "OPTION1" "OPTION2" "OPTION3" "OPTION4" --width=100 --height=300 --hide-header`

if [ "$ask" == "OPTION1" ]; then
    COMMAND_FOR_OPTION1
fi

if [ "$ask" == "OPTION2" ]; then
    COMMAND_FOR_OPTION2
fi

if [ "$ask" == "OPTION3" ]; then
    COMMAND_FOR_OPTION3
fi

if [ "$ask" == "OPTION4" ]; then
    COMMAND_FOR_OPTION4
fi
exit 0
```

When the window opens, no option is selected yet. To select (that is, **before** pressing Enter to apply):

- use the first letter (and arrows if more than one entry starts with that letter) or first letters
- any letter (that is any key except Enter, Backspace, Esc etc and modifiers) to select **first** entry and the up-down arrows for the rest.

[image]

- Esc to dismiss.

The default text "Select items from the list below"  can be edited by using the option `--text="Your text here"`; the color and font of that can be changed as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338724/4098390).

Comment: Can a similar approach be used for `kdialog`? I'm guessing instead of the more convenient `--list` one will have to use `--combobox`?

Comment: @DKBose - sorry, I do not use kdialog. Also, I have not created the script, just shared it here.

Comment: In any case, much appreciated. I'll play with kdialog since that's the "zenity" for KDE.

Comment: `[` doesn't have == operator. Use single = for string comparison, or `[[` if you plan to make it bash-specific. Better approach would be to use `case` statement instead. I'd be shorter and avoid pitfals of `[`

Comment: Also, please use command substitution `$(...)` instead of backticks.  This is easier to nest and avoids quoting issues

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - as stated in the question, I have only shared  script here that fitted my needs without any knowledge of the language. Please post in a separate answer the improved version of this or other scripts for all to enjoy.